# How to frame an exterior wall against a concrete wall (Replacing garage door with person door)?

Tags: concrete, framing, garage

I'm replacing my daylight basement garage door with a person door which means framing inside a concrete opening.

I know to use a pressure treated sill plate and sill gasket on the floor. But what about against the walls? PT and gasket again?

Comment: what does the building code say where you are?

Comment: Best reference I found was R317.1 of 2015icc code. By my reading it's not clear if studs against concrete must be PT.  I can't find anything on sil gaskets, or using the between studs and walls